# How to retry a consumed Observable?

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-networking

I am trying to re-execute a defined observable that failed. Using Retrofit2 and RxJava2 together i want to retry a specific request with its subscription and behavior when clicking a button. is that possible?

```
service.excecuteLoginService(url,
            tokenModel,
            RetrofitManager.apiKey)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(....)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742888/1584654

Comment: no irrelevant. at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply retries in a RXjava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740091/apply-retries-in-a-rxjava)

Comment: "re-execute a defined observable that failed" is exactly what `retry` does. If you need to use some more complex condition you can use `retryWhen` as explained in the linked answer.

Comment: @GVillani82 i want to be able to re execute it manually. i mean like when clicking on a button

Comment: Ok, now I get it! I'll try to answer

Comment: i will provide my solution as an answer after a while. thank you!!

Comment: @GVillani82 if i have an Observable that is already subscribed with `SubscribeWith(DisposableObserver)` does `retry` operator executes the service again with the pre-defined `DisposableObserver`?

Comment: Yep! , exactly!

Comment: Thank you. that was very helpful

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create Publisher, which emission is controlled by your button.

```
final PublishSubject<Object> retrySubject = PublishSubject.create();


service.excecuteLoginService(url,
            tokenModel,
            RetrofitManager.apiKey)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> showButton())
            .retryWhen(observable -> observable.zipWith(retrySubject, (o, o2) -> o))
            .subscribeWith(result -> {}, error -> {});
```

Your button will just emit an item from the `Subject`:

```
retrySubject.onNext(EMPTY);
```