# How to limit retryWhen count

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, reactivex

I'm using a PublishSubject in retryWhen to allow the user to retry the operation similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47677308/7935596). everything works fine but there's one problem -  after 3 times the user clicked retry I should not allow the retry anymore and should abort the operation. is there a way to limit the retry to 3 times?
I've tried publishSubject.take(3) operator but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please provide the `retryWhen` setup you were using. As I mentioned before, you can't stop a `flatMap` from inside by giving it an empty source.

Comment: I still don't have a retryWhen setup that works as I want it to work, if I would then no question would have been asked, I'm still trying to find a setup that works with my requirements...

Comment: "I'm using a PublishSubject in retryWhen". So do you have code or don't?

Comment: As I mentioned I have a test setup which is the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672224/retry-a-call-with-retrofit-2-and-rxjava2-after-displaying-a-dialog/47677308#47677308) but it doesn't fully fit with my requirements.

Comment: So what's stopping you to apply `take(3)` on the sequence returned from within `retryWhen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators, such as `retryWhen` have a secondary flow whose outcome affects the primary flow. Consequently, flow manipulation can be performed on this secondary flow as well, thus you can apply all sorts of operators to shape its outcome:

Adapting this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47677308/61158

```java
final PublishSubject<Object> retrySubject = PublishSubject.create();

disposable.add(
    getData()
    .doOnError(throwable -> enableButton())
    .retryWhen(observable -> 
        observable.zipWith(retrySubject, 
             (o, o2) -> o
        )
        .take(3)  // <------------------------ maximum 3 items from the secondary sequence
        .concatWith(Observable.error(new RetriesExhaustedException()));
     )
    .subscribeWith(/* do what you want with the result*/)
);
```

Comment: One last question, in this case changing from PublishSubject to SingleSubject will affect the take(3) operation?
I would like to reduce pitfalls and allow emitting only onNext() or onError()

Comment: Please think about what `SingleSubject` represents.

Comment: it means it will only emit 1 value or error, so I thought I will just create a new one in the flat map of the errorObservable. but it's hard to test whether it will defect the take(3) operation or not.

Comment: That makes no sense. What will call `onSuccess`/`onError` on those distinct `SingleSubject`s?

Comment: I'm passing it to the error handler by an interface method -  void onConnectionFailed(SingleSubject<Object> retrySubject);. And the error handler can choose to either call retrySubject.onError() and abort the retry or call retrySubject.onSuccess() to retry

Comment: and to onConnectionFailed(retrySubject) I'm calling from retrySubject.doOnSubscribe()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using retry or retryWhen, why not try this solution based on errors catch operation

```
let count = 0;
let retry_limit = 2;
from([1])
  .pipe(
    catchError((err, obs) => {
       if (count >= retry_limit) {
         return throwError(err)
       }
       count++
       return obs.pipe(delay(500))
  })
);
```